# Dropdown json data with JQuery displays "undefined" result

Tags: jquery, json, model-view-controller

I have a select, i want to fill with json data result but data appears "undefined". According to the scenario, when a button is pressed, the data according to the selected id will be sorted to the dropdown list.

```
<select id="myDropDown" name="myDropDown"></select>
```

```
function bindItems(MarkaID) {

        var MarkaID = 136; //entering data manually
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ MarkaID: MarkaID }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '/Home/GetUrunCinsleriForMarka'
        }).done(function (jsonObj) {

            var listItems = "";
            for (i in jsonObj) {

                listItems += "<option value='" + jsonObj[i].Key + "'>" + jsonObj[i].Value + "</option>";

            }
            $("#myDropDown").html(listItems);

        });
    }
```

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetUrunCinsleriForMarka(int MarkaID)
        {
            List<SqlParameter> sqlparameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            sqlparameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MarkaID", MarkaID));
            var urunCinsList = db.Database.SqlQuery<UrunCinsleriForMarka>("SP_GetUrunCinsleriForMarka @MarkaID", sqlparameters.ToArray());

            return Json(urunCinsList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Sample data id and value like this

```
96  | Power Supply
71  | Cameras
6   | Alarm Devices
118 | Mouse
11  | Fever-measuring devices
58  | Kettle
59  | ..............
137 | ..............
139 | ..............
```

Comment: check whether you are getting JSON response from the ajax call or not..

Comment: i have checked the result is coming

Comment: 0: {UrunCinsID: 96, UrunCinsi: "Power Supply"}
1: {UrunCinsID: 71, UrunCinsi: "Cameras"}
2: {UrunCinsID: 6, UrunCinsi: "Alarm Devices"}
3: {UrunCinsID: 118, UrunCinsi: "Mouse"}
4: {UrunCinsID: 11, UrunCinsi: "Fever-measuring devices"}
5: {UrunCinsID: 58, UrunCinsi: "Kettle"}
.
.
.
.

Comment: I have added a JFiddle Code. Give it a try https://jsfiddle.net/u5vek2jc/

Comment: Thanks for your help its worked.

Comment: I have added my answer below, check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made example code for your problem. Please go through following code:

HTML CODE:

```
<select id="questionNumber" class="form-control">
   <option>Select Number</option>
</select>
```

JQuery Code:

```
var result = {data:[
    {
    id:"5",
    number: "5"
  },
  {
    id: "89",
    number: "89"
  }
]}
$.each(result.data, function (key, value) {
    $("#questionNumber").append($('<option>', {
        value: value.id,
        text: value.number,
        'data-mark': value.id
    }));
});
```

JSFIddle Link Here:

https://jsfiddle.net/u5vek2jc/